# Configuring Multiple Identity Providers (IDPs) for SAML Authentication in Spring 5

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml, idp

I've successfully implemented SAML-based Single Sign-On (SSO) using Spring 5 with the guidance provided in the tutorial https://isd-soft.com/tech_blog/diving-sso-spring-saml-ssocircle/. The configuration is currently set up for a single Identity Provider (IDP), as outlined in the tutorial.

Now, I'm looking to expand the SSO setup to accommodate multiple IDPs. Specifically, I want to configure an additional IDP, allowing the system to redirect authentication requests to the appropriate IDP based on the URL endpoint. For instance, accessing /idp1 should direct users to IDP1 for authentication, and accessing /idp2 should redirect to IDP2 for authentication.

The technology stack I'm using includes:

**Spring 5**
**Dependency: spring-security-saml2-core version 1.0.10.RELEASE**
I'm seeking guidance on how to extend the existing SAML configuration to support multiple IDPs dynamically based on the URL endpoint. What changes or configurations do I need to make within the Spring SAML setup to enable this functionality?

Any insights, code examples, or relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello, a question, did you get to solve your question, I am in the same doubt and I am really looking for a way to do this, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you might need some refactoring but it seems that [spring-security (SAML federation chapter)](https://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/overview.html#federating-saml2-login) could be what you are looking for

You can find an example of usage [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/saml2/saml-extension-federation)